# Why is Kafka not deleting data?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a two node Kafka cluster with 48 gb disk allotted to each. 
The `server.properties` is set to retain logs upto 48 hours or log segments up to 1 GB. Here it is :

```
log.retention.hours=48
log.retention.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
```

I have 30 partitons for a topic. Here are the disk usage stats for one of these partitions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.9M Apr 14 00:06 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0G Apr 14 00:06 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 14 00:06 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10M Apr 14 12:43 00000000000001486744.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  73M Apr 14 12:43 00000000000001486744.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10M Apr 14 00:06 00000000000001486744.timeindex
```

As you can clearly see, we have a log segment of 1 gb. But as per my understanding, it should have already been deleted. Also, its been more than 48 hours since these logs were rolled out by Kafka. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you set `log.retention.bytes` and `log.segment.bytes` to the same value, which means there is always no candidate of deletable segment, so no delete happens.

The algorithm is:

1. firstly calculate the difference. In your case, the difference is 73MB (73MB + 1GB - 1GB)
2. Iterator all the non-active log segments, compare its size with the diff
3. If diff > log segment size, mark this segment deletable, and decrement the diff by the `size`
4. Otherwise, mark this segment undeletable and try with the next log segment.

Comment: Well, will it be okay to manually delete the old log segments and then restart the server? Our disk is almost at 80 % . Don't want to run into any catastrophic error.

Comment: Personally, I think it's doable since what Kafka does is to delete those log files including segment files and indexes and restarting the server helps updating the server metadata, but I strongly recommend a comprehensive testing though.

Comment: Indeed. I think Kafka does the same thing what I suggested to do manually. But it would be quite bold to do such a thing in production.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Let's say that `log.retention.hours` has value 24 hours and `log.retention.bytes` and `log.segment.bytes` are both set to 1 GB. When the value of the log reaches 1 GB (call this Old Log), a new log segment is created (call this New Log). The Old Log is then deleted 24 hours after the New Log is created.

In my case, the New Log was created about 25 hours before I posted this question. I dynamically changed the retention.ms value for a topic (which is maintained by Zookeeper, and not the Kafka cluster, and therefore does not require Kafka restart) to 24 hours, my old logs were immediately deleted.